# Is encrypt web.config a best practice

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, encryption, web-config

Currently, we are developing a website open for public. we are paying great attention on security.

we have a lot of sensitive information on web.config, such as db connection string in , should we encrypt these db connection string information ? alternatively, should we encrypt the whole web.config file ?

Could anyone give me some idea that how hacker get the web.config information ?

Comment: You should encrypt all sensitive information, at least. The rest is open to opinion. The way a hacker would get hold of the unencrypted web.config file could be through a security hole in your application (unvalidated paths to downloading files), a security hole in the server software (IIS?), a security hole in a completely different application running under a user with read access at least to your files, and about a million other reasons, including a "hacker" just breaking into the building and taking the whole server.

Comment: You wouldn't need to encrypt the connection string if you used Windows Security and a domain account with specific, restricted privileges. No risk of losing a password if there's no password to lose. It's also a lot easier to change service account passwords

Comment: As @PanagiotisKanavos comments, the best is to not require the sensitive information to be present at all but be built into the mechanisms already part of your environment.

Comment: In Windows 2012+ you can use [Group Managed Service Accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/group-managed-service-accounts/getting-started-with-group-managed-service-accounts). These are special accounts whose credentials are managed by the domain, in a manner similar to computer accounts. There's no visible password to lose. The actual password is changed every 30 days. A Group managed account can be used on multiple servers in a farm. A Standalone account (available since 2K8R2) only on a single machine

Answer (score 1):

The `web.config` is specifically excluded to be served by ASP.NET. You can't access that file unless you really screw up (that is: you can still read the file from disk of course and serve it yourself).

You do not need special protection for the outside world. The inside world can be as dangerous as the outside: if a lot of users have access to the web.config file from within your organisation, you might expose the username and password set in the connection string. It is better to use integrated security for that: you don't need usernames and passwords any more then. It doesn't get saver than that.